# How to visualize sensor_msgs/LaserScan without using RViz?

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all, thank you for reading this post.

i don't get any images in RViz, not even sensor_msgs/images, just a black screen. I think it's a bug. cause i can see them using image_view pack.
Now I want to visualize  sensor_msgs/LaserScan without using RVIz, Is there any other way to do this?

Any answers would be appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190375/how-to-visualize-sensor_msgs/laserscan-without-using-rviz?/) by [Rm4n2aa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19982/rm4n2aa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-08-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-08-16**:
did you select topic for displaying images?

**Comment by [Rm4n2aa](https://answers.ros.org/users/19982/rm4n2aa/) on 2014-08-16**:
Hello @bvbdort.
yes I did select the topic. and RViz is subscribing to the topic. but it shows just a black screen.

**Comment by [ahubers](https://answers.ros.org/users/10876/ahubers/) on 2014-08-17**:
In reference to the black screen, try updating your graphics drivers. This solved it for me (I too had the persistent black screen of death on every open of Rviz).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you add a screenshot of rviz, we can probably help you debug why it isn't working. rviz also has a [troubleshooting page](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz/Troubleshooting) that may be useful.

rviz really is the correct tool for visualizing data, because it understands the transform tree and can display different data sources in 3D, relative to one another.

If you just want to visualize your laser data to confirm that your laser is working, I wrote a [simple laser viewer](https://github.com/trainman419/Senior-Project/blob/c6eb0559a89af59a852c357f9e43303e80cda9bd/ros/laser_view/nodes/viewer.py) many years ago. I stopped using it once I discovered rviz.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-08-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0